# Array says length is 0 but it shows in control

Tags: angularjs, arrays, google-geocoder

Hi I'm trying to get latitude & longitude using geocoder as below code.

```
function getLatitudeLongitude(callback, address) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                callback(results[0]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

my API Success function is as below

```
var tempArr = [];
var posObj = {};

_.each(vm.result, function(data) {
    var tempPosArr = [];
        getLatitudeLongitude(function (result) {
        var tempPosArr = [];
            tempPosArr.push(result.geometry.location.lat());
            tempPosArr.push(result.geometry.location.lng());
            var posObj = {
                pos : tempPosArr
            };
            positions.push(posObj);
       }, data.location)
       console.log(positions);
});

console.log(positions.length);
```

I've declared this postions variable at global level. and data is being pushed but getting below result.

[image]

It got all latitude, Longitude and created Temp Obj even pushed but at outside, the result is as in Picture.

Comment: it is possible that by the time you inspected the array it had no child and then it god added later? @user422831

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, because this function : getLatitudeLongitude get data maybe from server and you need to use the Promise for this

ex:

```
var tempArr = [];
var posObj = {};
var defer = $q.defer(); // inject the $q service to add defer
_.each(vm.result, function(data) {
    var tempPosArr = [];
        getLatitudeLongitude(function (result) {
        var tempPosArr = [];
            tempPosArr.push(result.geometry.location.lat());
            tempPosArr.push(result.geometry.location.lng());
            var posObj = {
                pos : tempPosArr
            };
            positions.push(posObj);
           defer.resolve(positions);// now you resolve the promise 
       }, data.location)
       console.log(positions);
});

//console.log(positions.length);
// you can catch the promise here when it resolved 
defer.promise.then(function(positions){
 console.log(positions)
});
```